# Bug with "default" filter and boolean macro arguments in Twig / Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using [`default`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) Twig filter to specify arguments defaults in my [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html):

```
{% macro base(type, title, content, separator, dismissable) %}
{% spaceless %}

    {% debug dismissable %}

    {% set separator   = separator|default('!') %}
    {% set dismissable = dismissable|default(true) %}

    {% debug dismissable %}

    {# Beginning outputting... #}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

The **problem** is that `dismissable` argument type should be `boolean`. However when passing `false`the filter evaluates it and assign a `true` default value. An **example output**:

```
{{ base('success', 'Title', 'Hello', '!', false) }}

boolean false
boolean true
```

Is this a bug? Here is (part of) filter description:

> The default filter returns the passed default value if the value is
>   undefined or empty, otherwise the value of the variable.

Evaluation of boolean `false` is not even mentioned. My **temporary workaround** is:

```
{% set dismissable = dismissable is not defined or dismissable is null ?
    true : dismissable %}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not a bug. The docs you quoted mentions it, though it's far from being obvious:

> if the value is undefined or **empty**

Emphasis by me. False is an empty value.

[Twig_Node_Expression_Default](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Filter/Default.php) creates a [Twig_Node_Expression_Conditional](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Node/Expression/Conditional.php) in the code. In the end the default filter boiles down to the following php code:

```
$passed_value ? $passed_value : $default_value
```

In your case the passed value is false, so the expression returns the default value.

You should keep using your workaround.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [null-coalescing](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) operator `??` like this:

```
{% set dismissable = dismissable ?? true %}
```

That should solve your problem and it's a nice and clean solution. :-)

EDIT: It also solves the `default(false)` problem.

Comment: I *keep* forgetting null-coalescing is a thing in Twig. That's perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A replacement for the problematic expression `my_boolean|default(true)` (`my_boolean|default(false)` works as expected), can be `not my_boolean is defined or my_boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same "problem" and I did like this:

```
{% set dismissable = dismissable is not same as(false) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour as @Maerlyn already mentioned.
But you can take advantage of the `fallback` filter and simplify a bit your code.
This will work:
    `{% set dismissable = dismissable|fallback(true) %}`